# How to give bounce effect to my Table View in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am working on a project where i have used **tableView** to list numbers and had to set the **tableView** height according to its content size and further i have disabled the scroll of tableview to satisfy my design. But the problem is when i have disabled it the bounce effect also got disabled.

*Is there is any way to give it a bounce effect and at a time disabling the scroll?*

Comment: I think you first need to read this documentation [Bounce property](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollview)

Comment: if the height of your table is longer that a single screen, you need to be able to scroll. Not sure why you want to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

No. The bounce property of the `UITableview` works when scrolling is enabled.
So it is not possible to work it when scrolling is disabled.

Instead you can increase/decrease the height of the `UITableview` based on the rows.

Comment: how increasing or decreasing height will help me to get the bounce effect ?

Comment: Place `UITableview` inside a view.

Comment: yes my tableview is under a view and i as i have said i have updated its height according to content size.